# I need to parse json array which consist of array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here is my JSON array which I need to parse using javascript code.

{
"individualTicketList": [{
"TicketID": 58,
"ResponderID": 1,
"Subject": "test sub",
"DueByDate": "2021-10-12"
},
{
"TicketID": 59,
"ResponderID": 1,
"Subject": "test",
"DueByDate": "2021-10-12"
}]
}

```
I am having an above json array and i need to display subject of each object from my json `which is inside individualticketlist  here is my code.`

for(var i=0;i<jsonString.length;i++)
{
alert(a.individualTicketList[i].DueByDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to loop through it

```js
let json = {
  "individualTicketList": [{
    "TicketID": 58,
    "ResponderID": 1,
    "Subject": "test sub",
    "DueByDate": "2021-10-12"
  }, {
    "TicketID": 59,
    "ResponderID": 1,
    "Subject": "test",
    "DueByDate": "2021-10-12"
  }]
}

let arr = json["individualTicketList"]

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].Subject);
  console.log(arr[i].DueByDate);
  //your other code here
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Subject')

Comment: I am not sure how you run it. The snippet above displays the output when you run it

Comment: Yes in snippet it works fine but giving an error after integration

Comment: You need to add more details. where is your json coming from? console it before running the for loop. It could also be the json is undefined at the time when the loop runs. I can't say more without having more details